# Open the app in a specific tab in tabbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, tabbar

I have an app with a TabBar with 5 tabs (regular tab bar with no custom class). When I start the app the left tab is opened. I want it to open the middle one first. I've tried putting

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

in the ViewDidLoad of the ViewController that is first opened but the tab isn't switching.
**I can see it's highlighted but not selected.** If I put the code above under `viewWillAppear` it will be selected on first run but when I'll select the left tab from time to time it will jump to the middle one.

Also tried this without success:

```
DetailsViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the TabBar added from Interface builder or using code?

Comment: Interface. And dragging triggered segaues to viewcontrollers

Comment: Maybe [next link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195316/iphone-how-i-hide-a-tab-bar-button) help you, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Try setting it in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

like [self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Writing it here so I'll update the question in 2 days.in appdelegate:  `UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [tabBar setSelectedIndex:2]; 
`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the only solution that worked for me. in appdelegate:

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController; 
[tabBar setSelectedIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 1):

In storyboard set custom class to the tabbarController and in that custom class

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to call

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = desiredIndex;
```

Inside applicationDidLaunch.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: if your tabbar controller is rootViewController like

```
`[self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something hackish in the past. I have found in order for each tab to become active, in my applicationDidFinishLaunching, I need to loop through all my view controllers then access the "view" property:

```
for(viewController in arrayOfViewController)
{
    // will load the view controller into memory
    [viewController view];
}
```

Don't know if you can make any use of it.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you use tab bar controller you can do those steps. It worked on my project.

- Create a tab bar controller
- Create new Cocoatouch Class
- Write this code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
   
    @IBInspectable var initialIndex = 2

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        selectedIndex = initialIndex
    }

}
```

I chose the 3rd tab bar, but you can change `initialIndex` as you wish.